# Security implications of Android apps that require Accessibility access

Tags: android

Occasionally, an Android app will require access to Accessibility services.

As an example, see [App Hibernator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ruh.hibernator).

What are the security implications of allowing an app access to Android's Accessibility services?

Obviously, it can record every keystroke.  Are there any other concerns?

Does the situation change if the device is rooted, even if the app does not use root privileges?

Are there different concerns depending on the version of Android?